# Azure Blob Storage get file list from specific directory not from container

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage

I have created code to getting the files list from the Azure blob container.

```
const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);

 const containerName = `newcontainer${new Date().getTime()}`;
  const containerClient = new ContainerClient(
    `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}`,
    sharedKeyCredential
  );


 console.log("Listing all blobs");
  i = 1;
  for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
    console.log(`Blob ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
  }
```

above code return list of all files.
but in my container, there are two folders one is **IN** folder and the second is **OUT** folder. I just need only the files list from **IN** folder.

is that any function available to get a list from a specific directory?

Answer (score 3):

Just add `prefix` option in your `listBlobsFlat` method and you will be able to list blobs from `IN` folder only. Something like:

```
for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat({prefix: 'IN/'})) {
    console.log(`Blob ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
}
```

You can learn more about blob listing options here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/containerlistblobsoptions?view=azure-node-latest